# How do I activate css modules after running eject in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx

In my React project, I want to activate CSS modules, I ran eject but don't know where to set modules to "true" because I can't seem to find "webpack.config.dev.js"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHg38.png)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using CRA. The CSS modules are supported out of the box (and without eject). In `webpack.config.js` you can find `const cssModuleRegex = /\.module\.css$/;`
 and `const sassModuleRegex = /\.module\.(scss|sass)$/;`. For more info check documentation of CRA -> https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet